# Define a root path in the router with Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I'd like to know if it's possible to set a specific folder to be my root path for my routes/views/templates/controllers?

For example, my project looks something like this:

```
/controllers
  /base
  /main
    /index.js
    /welcome
      /index.js

/routes
  /base
  /main
    /index.js
    /welcome
      /index.js

/templates
  /main
    /index.hbs
    /welcome
      /index.hbs

/views
  /base
  /main
    /index.js
    /welcome
      /index.js
```

My `main` folder is my root folder for all my controllers, routes, templates and views.

Using the URL:

- `mywebsite.com` would access the page in `/main/index.js`
- `mywebsite.com/welcome` would access the page in `/main/welcome/index.js`

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to have two ember app nested inside each other ?

Comment: No, I have a `base` folder which contains "abstract" classes (such abstract views, abstract controllers etc.. that some of my pages extend) and I don't want to mix this up with the normal pages

Comment: Are you using Ember-CLI?

Comment: Yes I'm using the latest version

Comment: You're going to want to override the Ember-CLI resolver then. I'm not 100% sure how to do that in your situation, but I'll take a stab at it and try to get back to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish this by supplying the root route an empty path:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('main', { path: '' }, function() {
    this.resource('main.welcome', { path: 'welcome' }, function() {});
  });
});
```

`mywebsite.com` gives you `main/index.js` and `mywebsite.com/welcome` gives you `main/welcome/index.js`.